# Count number of columns in multiple csv files in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, csv

I have a directory that contains a large number of CSV files (more than 1000). I am using python pandas library to count the number of columns in each CSV file.

But the problem is that the separator used in some of CSV file is not  only`"," but "|" and ";"`

How to tackle this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
from collections import OrderedDict

path="C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\Sample_Data_August10\\outbound"

files=os.listdir(path)

col_count_dict=OrderedDict() 
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,file),error_bad_lines=False,sep=",|;|\|",engine='python')

    col_count_dict[file]=len(df.columns)
```

I am storing it as a dictionary.

I am getting an error like:

`Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used`

I have used `sep=None`, but that didn't work.

**Edit**  :
**One of the csv is like this** :
`Number|CommentText|CreationDate|Detail|EventDate|ProfileLocale_ISO|Event_Number|Message_Number|ProfileInformation_Number|Substitute_UserNo|User_UserNo`


**Second one is like:**
`Number,Description`

I can't reveal the data. I have just given the column name as the data is sensitive.

#### Update

After a little bit of tweaking and using print status to figure out using the code of andrey-portnoy, I came to know that csv sniffer was identifying the delimiter for "|" as "e" so using an if statement I changed it back to "|". Now it is giving me correct output.
Also in place of `read()` , I used `readline()` . in following line of code in Andrey's answer : `dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))`

But the problem remains unsolved. I was able to figure out this after a lot of inspection but every time I may not be correct to guess and this can lead to error. 

 
Any help will be awaited.

Comment: Hey @Atif. Have you tried running this without using  sep= At all? Pandas does a pretty good job of working out the delimiter for you. So... “df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,file),error_bad_lines=False,engine='python’)”

Comment: @ChrisA , No it doesn't work. It gives columns count as 1 even though it is not 1  for separator having "|"

Answer (score 1):

By specifying the separator as `sep=",|;|\|"`, you make that whole string a separator.

Instead, you want to use the [Sniffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) from the `csv` module to detect the CSV dialect used in each file, in particular the delimiter.

For example, for a single file `example.csv`:

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
sep = dialect.delimiter

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep=sep)
```

Don't enable the Python engine by default, as it is much slower.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error as :
`raise Error, "Could not determine delimiter"
_csv.Error: Could not determine delimiter`

Comment: @Atif Can you include a couple lines from the CSV file?

Comment: @Atif What happens if you run `pd.read_csv(file, sep='|')` on the file with `|` as the separator?

Comment: I tried to print the `sep` to see if it is catching the separator correctly and found that for the "|"  delimited file it is giving `sep` as "e" . That's why it is failing.

Comment: If I just give sep="|" it gives the correct output  for that file